# draw heart shape android canvas

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

hi i want to draw heart shape i know how to use drawCircle() and some other canvas classes but how to draw heart shape

i have an equation which create heart shape

```
   polar r = (sin(t)*sqrt(abs(cos(t))))/(sin(t) + 7/5) -2*sin(t) + 2
```

this is link [heart shape](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20r=%28sin%28t%29%2asqrt%28abs%28cos%28t%29%29%29%29/%28sin%28t%29%20%2b%207/5%29%20-2%2asin%28t%29%20%2b%202) where u can more understand what i want.

thanks in advance

Comment: Okay this is a duplicate of your prior question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324429/convert-circle-into-heart-2d-android. What have you tried?

Comment: nope its not duplicate u can check it

Comment: Okay so what is it don't you understand such that you don't know how to draw it.

Comment: yes i don't know how to draw a heart shape last time i used drawCircle of canvas but heart is not there

Comment: i used this code

<pre>    c.drawCircle(circle.x + this.offsetX, circle.y
       + this.offsetY, circle.radius, paint);</pre>

Comment: just use a drawable resource and don't complicate it:)

Comment: If you can't draw the parametric curve, try this: draw two circles side by side, slightly overlapping, for the top of the heart. Fill with a solid color. Then draw a solid-filled V-shaped triangle overlapping the bottom of the circles, to make the point of the heart. Adjust the size and location of each shape, and you'll have a decent heart.

Comment: While not a parametric curve you can totally draw a heart with a path and two quad statements. Also, if you were actually wanting something to actually draw a parametric curve you could use a small increments of t and go from 0 to 2pi doing lineto commands in path. for (double t = 0; t < 2*Math.PI; t+= 0.01) double r = (parametric equation); path.lineto(Math.cos(t)*r,Math.sin(t)*r); -- Or thereabouts. Easy as Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas.drawCircle only knows how to draw circles not 'parametric curves'. I would advise that you look that up in a math book first so that you understand what is happening before trying to write the code for it.

Comment: thanks for suggestion Morrison Chang but my maths is too weak that why i am unable to work on it sorry i am wasting your time